# Rotating arm bone twists and distorts mesh

Tags: modeling, rigging, weight-painting

I have the following model of a frog, which is rigged and assigned weights. In its neutral pose, the frog is lying down, but I want to animate it sitting. I started animating and noticed rotating the arm bone greatly distorts and twists the area, as shown in Image 3. What am I doing wrong? I'm pretty new to Blender and 3D modelling in general. I've already tried subdividing the arm area and tweaking the weights (which are currently set to include the entire arm and a few faces where the arm connects to the body, which I've already tried removing to no avail.)[image: Frog_SideView] [image: Frog_TopView][image: Image_3_Twists_Distortions][image: Image_4_Twists_Distortions_SideView]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have to actually deal with a rotation, you have to distribute this rotation smoothly along some different edgeloops. This is an example of how it can be achieved.

[image]